# problem FFmpeg avcodec_register_all iphone

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg

I need to use ffmpeg for encodig.
I have all *.a.
My problem is tha when I use avcodec_register_all() xcode give me this error:

"_deflate", referenced from:

```
  _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(pngenc.o)


  _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(pngenc.o)


  _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(pngenc.o)


  _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(lclenc.o)


  _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(lclenc.o)


  _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(zmbvenc.o)
```

"_deflateEnd", referenced from:

```
  _flashsv_encode_end in libavcodec.a(flashsvenc.o)


  _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(pngenc.o)


  _encode_end in libavcodec.a(lclenc.o)


  _encode_end in libavcodec.a(zmbvenc.o)
```

"_compress", referenced from:

```
  _encode_strip in libavcodec.a(tiffenc.o)


 (maybe you meant: _mp3_header_compress_bsf$non_lazy_ptr, _mp3_header_compress_bsf )
```

"_vorbis_analysis_init", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_lame_set_bWriteVbrTag", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"_lame_set_VBR", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"_crc32", referenced from:

```
  _png_write_chunk in libavcodec.a(pngenc.o)


  _png_write_chunk in libavcodec.a(pngenc.o)


  _png_write_chunk in libavcodec.a(pngenc.o)
```

"_x264_encoder_headers", referenced from:

```
  _X264_init in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
```

"_lame_encode_buffer", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"_x264_encoder_encode", referenced from:

```
  _X264_frame in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
```

"_vorbis_comment_add_tag", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_theora_encode_tables", referenced from:

```
  _encode_init in libavcodec.a(libtheoraenc.o)
```

"_vorbis_block_init", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_x264_nal_encode", referenced from:

```
  _X264_frame in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)


  _X264_init in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
```

"_uncompress", referenced from:

```
  _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(cscd.o)


  _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(dxa.o)


  _svq3_decode_init in libavcodec.a(h264.o)


  _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(tiff.o)
```

"_xvid_plugin_2pass2", referenced from:

```
  _ff_xvid_rate_control_init in libavcodec.a(libxvid_rc.o)


  _ff_xvid_rate_estimate_qscale in libavcodec.a(libxvid_rc.o)


  _ff_xvid_rate_estimate_qscale in libavcodec.a(libxvid_rc.o)


  _ff_xvid_rate_control_uninit in libavcodec.a(libxvid_rc.o)


  _xvid_plugin_2pass2$non_lazy_ptr in libavcodec.a(libxvidff.o)


 (maybe you meant: _xvid_plugin_2pass2$non_lazy_ptr)
```

"_lame_set_num_channels", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"_lame_set_VBR_q", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"_vorbis_analysis_buffer", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_compress2", referenced from:

```
  _flashsv_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsvenc.o)
```

"_inflateEnd", referenced from:

```
  _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(pngdec.o)


  _flashsv_decode_end in libavcodec.a(flashsv.o)


  _decode_end in libavcodec.a(lcldec.o)


  _decode_end in libavcodec.a(tscc.o)


  _decode_end in libavcodec.a(zmbv.o)
```

"_lame_encode_buffer_interleaved", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"_theora_comment_clear", referenced from:

```
  _encode_init in libavcodec.a(libtheoraenc.o)
```

"_x264_encoder_close", referenced from:

```
  _X264_close in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
```

"_inflate", referenced from:

```
  _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(pngdec.o)


  _flashsv_decode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsv.o)


  _flashsv_decode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsv.o)


  _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(lcldec.o)


  _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(lcldec.o)


  _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(lcldec.o)


  _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(tscc.o)


  _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(zmbv.o)
```

"_theora_comment_init", referenced from:

```
  _encode_init in libavcodec.a(libtheoraenc.o)
```

"_vorbis_info_init", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"*deflateInit2*", referenced from:

```
  _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(pngenc.o)
```

"_deflateReset", referenced from:

```
  _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(lclenc.o)


  _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(zmbvenc.o)
```

"_theora_encode_init", referenced from:

```
  _encode_init in libavcodec.a(libtheoraenc.o)
```

"_lame_get_framesize", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"_vorbis_analysis", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_inflateReset", referenced from:

```
  _flashsv_decode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsv.o)


  _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(lcldec.o)


  _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(lcldec.o)


  _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(tscc.o)


  _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(zmbv.o)
```

"_lame_set_disable_reservoir", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"_inflateSync", referenced from:

```
  _flashsv_decode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsv.o)
```

"_vorbis_info_clear", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_close in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_theora_encode_header", referenced from:

```
  _encode_init in libavcodec.a(libtheoraenc.o)
```

"_theora_clear", referenced from:

```
  _encode_close in libavcodec.a(libtheoraenc.o)
```

"_theora_info_clear", referenced from:

```
  _encode_init in libavcodec.a(libtheoraenc.o)
```

"_xvid_plugin_lumimasking", referenced from:

```
  _xvid_plugin_lumimasking$non_lazy_ptr in libavcodec.a(libxvidff.o)


 (maybe you meant: _xvid_plugin_lumimasking$non_lazy_ptr)
```

"_theora_encode_comment", referenced from:

```
  _encode_init in libavcodec.a(libtheoraenc.o)
```

"_lame_set_brate", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)


  _MP3lame_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"_theora_encode_YUVin", referenced from:

```
  _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(libtheoraenc.o)
```

"_lame_init", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"_lame_set_mode", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"*deflateInit*", referenced from:

```
  _encode_init in libavcodec.a(lclenc.o)


  _encode_init in libavcodec.a(zmbvenc.o)
```

"_vorbis_encode_setup_managed", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_lame_set_quality", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)


  _MP3lame_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"_vorbis_analysis_blockout", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)


  _oggvorbis_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_vorbis_analysis_wrote", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)


  _oggvorbis_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)


  _oggvorbis_encode_close in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"*inflateInit*", referenced from:

```
  _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(pngdec.o)


  _flashsv_decode_init in libavcodec.a(flashsv.o)


  _decode_init in libavcodec.a(lcldec.o)


  _decode_init in libavcodec.a(tscc.o)


  _decode_init in libavcodec.a(zmbv.o)
```

"_vorbis_comment_clear", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_vorbis_bitrate_addblock", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_lame_set_in_samplerate", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"_vorbis_encode_ctl", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_x264_param_default", referenced from:

```
  _X264_init in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
```

"_theora_info_init", referenced from:

```
  _encode_init in libavcodec.a(libtheoraenc.o)
```

"_vorbis_encode_setup_init", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_vorbis_comment_init", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_vorbis_bitrate_flushpacket", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)


  _oggvorbis_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_xvid_plugin_single", referenced from:

```
  _xvid_plugin_single$non_lazy_ptr in libavcodec.a(libxvidff.o)


 (maybe you meant: _xvid_plugin_single$non_lazy_ptr)
```

"_xvid_global", referenced from:

```
  _ff_xvid_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libxvidff.o)
```

"_xvid_encore", referenced from:

```
  _ff_xvid_encode_close in libavcodec.a(libxvidff.o)


  _ff_xvid_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libxvidff.o)


  _ff_xvid_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(libxvidff.o)
```

"_vorbis_encode_setup_vbr", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_lame_set_out_samplerate", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"_lame_init_params", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"_vorbis_block_clear", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_close in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_lame_encode_flush", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"_x264_encoder_open", referenced from:

```
  _X264_init in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
```

"_lame_close", referenced from:

```
  _MP3lame_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)


  _MP3lame_encode_close in libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)
```

"_vorbis_dsp_clear", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_close in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_vorbis_analysis_headerout", referenced from:

```
  _oggvorbis_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libvorbis.o)
```

"_theora_encode_packetout", referenced from:

```
  _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(libtheoraenc.o)


  _encode_close in libavcodec.a(libtheoraenc.o)
```

ld: symbol(s) not found

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Also whene i use
[code]
codec = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_H264); //CODEC_ID_H264
 //codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("mpeg1"); 
 if (!codec) {
  fprintf(stderr, "codec not found\n");
  exit(1);
 }[/code]
codec is always null

where is my error?
best regards

Comment: How are you building/obtaining the codec libs (libmp3lame and so forth?) all your linker errors seem to be to libraries that ffmpeg depends on per your configure.

Answer (score 12):

Right click on the project select Add->Existing Frameworks, then add libz.dylib.